# AC adapter triggers calculator

Tags: 15.04

When the AC adapter is connected or disconnected the calculator key is being triggered too. Here's the output of `acpi_listen`, the calculator key is the 2nd line (ff):

```
ac_adapter ACPI0003:00 00000080 00000000
 PNP0C14:00 000000ff 00000000
processor LNXCPU:00 00000081 00000000
processor LNXCPU:01 00000081 00000000
processor LNXCPU:02 00000081 00000000
processor LNXCPU:03 00000081 00000000
battery PNP0C0A:00 00000080 00000001
```

Any thoughts?